# Word for Master Apprentice structure of a community

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for crafts which are most normally only learned by serving as a protege/apprentice to an existing skilled craftsmen until such a time as proficiency is reached (this relationship need not be formal).

That is, there exists no resources for self learning that would be reasonably considered sufficient to allow one to operate without such an apprenticeship, or that such attempts would be rejected by the community. Some examples might include Academia or martial arts.

Comment: Could you give us the _context_ in which you want to use this word? The general word for things learnt from craftsmen/women is _crafts_.

Answer (score 1):

The only trades, crafts, or professions that are going to require apprenticeship are, I believe you will find, those licensed by government and requiring some kind of work experience by law or as a condition for taking a licensing exam.

In the U.S., this includes, in most states, the CPA and MD licenses, and in some states jobs as trivial as florist.

This sort of licensing is often an attempt to control entry by people already in the profession, although generally justified on public safety grounds.

Note, for example, licenses for school teachers but not college professors.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licensure

Comment: You cannot become a college professor without a PhD. A PhD can only be acquired under the direct guidance of a college professor. It is, by any reasonable definition apparent to myself, an apprenticeship. Your notion of licensing is much more specific than the questions notion of apprenticeship.

Comment: It is not true that you must have a Ph.D. to be a college professor. It may be typical, but not required.  In getting an advanced degree you may teach or be a teaching assistant, but this is far from being an apprenticeship.

Comment: It is not true that an application for a college professorship without a PhD will be considered. In fact, for many positions it is remarkably hard to be considered even with years of post-graduate research and teaching experience. Your failure is to believe that requirements that exist de facto, and not de jure, are not requirements. They are.

Answer (score -1):

"Trades" is what comes to mind, commonly known as physical skills learned either in a vocational school or as an apprentice to a master tradesman or craftsman.

Comment: I don't think that can be correct as the OP mentions *Some examples might include Academia or martial arts.*